# How to use static variable inside main in Java

Tags: java

Forgive me, I'm a beginner to Java. On an assignment, I had to create a program that prints a table of temperatures from 32 to 98 using a for loop, along with conversions to celsius and kelvin. I keep getting the error "non-static variable x cannot be referenced from a static context". The thing is, I fixed x to DecimalFormat as x.format, and attempted to apply it to the conversions to two decimal places. It's recognizing x as a variable instead of the name of the function. Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    int i;

    for(i = 32; i <= 98; i++){

        System.out.println((i)+"F"+(x.format(i-32)*(5/9))+"C"+(x.format(i-32)*(5/9)+273.15))+"K");
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a variable `x` defined anywhere.

Comment: THere are no static variables either.

Answer (score 0):

In your class, you have a member variable `x` which is not static. When you use it in your main class which IS static, the exception is thrown.

**First way:**

So what you need to do is to change the modifier of `x` to static like this:

```
static x; // with your modifiers
```

then you can use it in your main method without trouble.

**Second way:**

If this is a relatively big project (or medium), you might want to consider using another function and calling that function from the main loop to avoid having to deal with all these static stuff. Here is how:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    YOUR_CLASS_NAME c = new YOUR_CLASS_NAME();
    c.startLogic();
}
public void startLogic(){
    System.out.println((i)+"F"+(x.format(i-32)*(5/9))+"C"+(x.format(i-32)*(5/9)+273.15))+"K");
}
```

Remember to change `YOUR_CLASS_NAME` to your class name (duh).

Comment: @AaronMarcus please accept the answer as thank you :-)